# AJAX Calendar Extender was not popup when i click on Text box

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendar

WebConfig:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false">
    <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ACT" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </controls>
</pages>
```

ASPX:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ACT"%>
```

```
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Opportunity Start Date" CssClass="style2"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>                
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Width="150px" CssClass="style2" format ="dd/mm/yyyy" ></asp:TextBox>
    <ACT:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" PopupButtonID="TextBox7" TargetControlID="TextBox7" PopupPosition="Right"></ACT:CalendarExtender>
</td>
```

When i click on Text box AJAX Calendar Extender was not showing the calendar popup. Am I miss anything in above code.
I added AJAX Tool Kit dll file into bin directory. 
I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 express.

Comment: didi you have ToolScriptManage or ScriptManager on your page?

Comment: Yeah.. I added Script Manager 


<asp:scriptmanager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>

Comment: Replace it to ToolScriptManager.

Comment: Error 9 Unknown server tag 'asp:ToolScriptManager'. C:\Users\002410\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\Default2.aspx 44

Comment: not asp its ajax toolkitscriptmanager  for you `<ACT:ToolkitScriptManager ID="Scriptmanager" runat="server"></ACT:ToolkitScriptManager>`

Comment: Again Same error was showing...

Comment: Error 9 Unknown server tag 'ACT:ToolkitManager'. C:\Users\002410\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\Default2.aspx 44

Comment: Its <ACT:ToolkitScriptManager>

Comment: Thank you Rojalin... Build is Successful, but it was showing this error in webpage...
Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxMin, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: may this is because of some Ajax control toolkit reference.http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-AjaxMin-The-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified.aspx visit this may you get solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Ajax ToolkitScript Manager `<ACT:ToolkitScriptManager ID="Scriptmanager" runat="server"></ACT:ToolkitScriptManager>`